# Reverse page margin in scrreprt

Tags: margins, marginpar, marginnote, scrreprt

Could anyone amend the following code to give a document whose margins are on the right, rather than the left? The header should still extend over the margin.

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi, titlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
vmargin=2.5cm, heightrounded,
left=6cm, right=2cm,
marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm,
showframe
]{geometry}



\usepackage[
automark,
headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\the\marginparwidth-  \the\marginparsep:marginpar,
footwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\the\marginparwidth-\the\marginparsep:marginpar
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\ohead{\normalfont MATH UNIT}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext\marginpar{Margin text}
\Blindtext\marginpar{Margin text}
\Blindtext[1]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the settings for `left` and `right` in the geometry options. For the header and footer position set the offsets to 0pt explicitly. (I do not know why this is necessary.)

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi, titlepage]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[
vmargin=2.5cm, heightrounded,
left=2cm, right=6cm,% <- changed
marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm,
showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[
automark,
headsepline,% <- to show the headwidth
footsepline,% <- to show the footwidth
headwidth=textwithmarginpar:0pt:0pt,% <- changed
footwidth=textwithmarginpar:0pt:0pt% <- changed
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\ohead{\normalfont MATH UNIT}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext\marginpar{Margin text}
\Blindtext\marginpar{Margin text}
\Blindtext[1]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used options `headsepline` and `footsepline` to show the positions of header and footer.

[image]